# Llamar a un teléfono desde link en landing o en email

Tags: html, email, enlace

si bien pude resolver lo de activar el teléfono al hacer clic en una imagen o botón,
lo que estoy necesitando es que, al hacer clic, **se active la llamada directamente**, o sea no solo que se abra el teléfono para llamar sino que directamente llame. ¿Es posible?
¡Gracias!

Comment: Deberías poner el código que llevas para así saber que has usado y que no. De cualquier modo te dejo una posible solución en la caja de respuestas.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

No sé si has intentado usar el atributo `:tel` de HTML con el que puedes indicar el número de teléfono al que quieres llamar:

```html
<a href="tel:+50212345678">Contacto: +502 1234-5678</a>
```

Tienes que indicar el código del país y el número al que se quiere llamar. Esa es la única manera que yo veo y conozco para realizar una llamada desde HTML, espero te sirva.